# Auto redirect Explanation

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm configuring a paypal payment gateway in my website, at the moment a sandbox is configured and I'm using paypal standard. Everithing works fine except for some small thing I need to discuss with you:

1. after user (redirected to paypal site) make the payment is there a way to redirect automatically after the payment is done...I would avoid that user has to click the link: "return to xxx website". ( I have seen and used many websites that use to redirect to paypal but after payments is done the really automatically redirect to the website...without any additional click)
2. I have personalized the aspect of my page under paypal account (in sandbox mode) but when i test the payment the page is not personalized but show the standard one...so my question is personalized pages works under sandbox?
3. For paypal standard subscribe button is required an HTTPS protocol or they accept also normal urls?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using **PayPal Payments Standard** (Buttons) then you will have the return to merchant at the checkout page, this is because the payment is complete at this point. What you are thinking when you are redirected back immediately is **ExpressCheckout** and the merchant can process the payment immediately or by user action.

2) Yes, personalized pages work in sandbox. You need to make sure it is set as primary

3) For **PayPal Payments Standard** you do not need HTTPS, as the payment is handled on the Paypal website.